# how to detect Availability zonal failure automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, availability-zone

Are there any techniques available to automatically detect Availability zonal failure in Amazon Web Services?

I tried Lambda function to check the status AZ but i want to try another way. Is there any other way to detect the failure automatically.

when there is a failure i should get a email

Answer (score 0):

You can try these alternative approaches.

**First**: You can try AWS Cloudwatch Metric to detect your service health For example for Ec2 Instance the [`StatusCheckFailed`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) metric can be monitored. Then create an SNS topic to trigger an alarm which sends an email, as soon as it meets a specific threshold. Check this [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/US_SetupSNS.html) to create SNS topic.

**Second**: You could also try [AWS Health](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/health/latest/ug/what-is-aws-health.html) Dashboard to monitor the aws Resources status

Comment: I want use AWS Health Dashboard to check the status of availability zone . If there is any failure in AZ  we can get notifications for events that might affect services and resources using Event Bridge rule ? What the event pattern for availability zone failure